# Switching off AWS instance automatically once a job is done

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine, lsf

I have a Linux desktop. I would like to be able to run on it a job that does the following:

1. switches on an AWS instance
2. deploys and runs a Docker script on it
3. once the script finished it switches off the AWS instance

Basically, my Linux desktop would be a sort of master which switches on on demand slave work nodes. And then switches them off once the job is done.

Is there a framework/tool that does this? I'm looking for an analogy of SGE/LSF in which the master node is non-aws while the slave nodes are aws instances. And the scripts which are deployed are docker-ised.

P.S. While typing this it occurred to me that this might be what a Docker machine is supposed to do. I haven't used it yet so would welcome comments on such an option.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Batch can run a Docker job.  It could be just what you need.  See the docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/Batch_GetStarted.html).

Answer (score 0):

On desktop you can run
`aws ec2 stop-instances`.
Try `aws ec2 stop-instances help` for details.

How to set up - [official guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html)